# Cannot send email to user on registering in Laravel

Tags: php, gmail, email, laravel-7

I searched everywhere, tried to unlock the "LESS SECURE APPS" in my account, tried to unlock the capchat. But nothing helped. Is there any other thing to do?

This the error:

```
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "my@gmail.com" using 3 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
 535 5.7.8
```

.env file

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=MY-GMAIL@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=MY-PASSWORD
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=THE-SENDER-EMAIL@outlook.pt
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Controller Class code

```
public function build()
    {
        return $this
            ->subject('Your account created with success!')
            ->replyTo('MY-REPLY-MAIL@outlook.pt')
            ->view('emails.user-registered')
            ->with(['user' => $this->user]); 
    }
```

Comment: Check if you email has 2 step verification enabled?

Comment: 2 step is off. Should I turn it ON?

Comment: Let's debug it step by step.
Visit below link and just turn ON the settings (if its OFF):
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: I did it already before, did not work. The "Less secure apps"

Comment: Please also try `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` same as `MAIL_USERNAME`.

Comment: Also enclose your password in double quotes i.e. MAIL_PASSWORD="MY-PASSWORD"

Comment: Still continue with the error.

Comment: Ohh! I think, i got it! The problem in double quotes and i should turn on the "LES SECURE APPS... @sssurii thanks so much. I appreciated so much. Thanks

Comment: No, you have keep Less Secure Apps setting on.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just posting maybe someone will need it. 
I solved the problem turning on the less secure apps in my account [Less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)

And I put the password in double quotes.

I hope its help someone else.